# Como funcionam os métodos usados dentro de classes?

Tags: ruby

É muito comum no Ruby usarmos métodos dentro de classes, como o `attr_accessor`, ou até mesmo de bibliotecas, como o `validates_presence_of`, do Ruby on Rails.

Gostaria de criar:

```
class Person
  add_name_getter "Luiz"
end
```

Que adicionasse um campo `name` à classe, com o valor passado, como `"Luiz"`, no exemplo acima.

```
p = Person.new
p.name == "Luiz" # true
```

<sup>Sei que é um algo inútil, mas é só para fins de exemplo.</sup>

Tentei criar um método como esse:

```rb
def add_name_getter *args
  puts args.to_s
end
```

Porém, eu não recebi como parâmetro nenhuma instância ou referência da classe.

---

Diante disso, ficam as questões:

- Como se chamam essas construções?
- O que são exatamente essas construções que são usadas nas classes (referi a elas como "métodos", apesar de que não saber se são exatamente métodos);
- Como posso criar uma construção dessas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse tipo de "construção" é um **método**, mas em [alguns casos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322094/7445826) também são referidos como `macros`. Então, quando fazemos:

```rb
class MyClass
  some_method()
end
```

O método `some_method` está sendo executado no momento em que `MyClass` é avaliada. Para entender isso, é preciso saber que, diferentemente de linguagens como Java ou C++, `class` não é somente uma definição, mas uma expressão que é avaliada — e é nesse momento que `some_method` é invocado. <sup>[Adaptado de outra resposta do StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby/4371087#4371087)</sup>

Vale ressaltar, ainda, que elas são chamadas implicitamente com `self`, então, na verdade, o que está ocorrendo é o seguinte:

```rb
class MyClass
  self.some_method()
end
```

Isso significa que `some_method` deve ser um **método da classe, e não um método da instância**. Desse modo, há várias formas de se implementar esse `some_method`, tais como:

Na própria classe:

```rb
class MyClass
  def self.some_method
    puts "Hello, world!"
  end

  some_method
end
```

Em uma classe pai, que será herdada:

```rb
class Parent
  def self.some_method
    puts "Hello, world!"
  end
end

class MyClass < Parent
  some_method
end
```

---

Com isso, para implementarmos o referido `add_name_getter`, podemos fazer assim:

```rb
class UtilsClass
  def self.add_name_getter value
    # Criamos um método `:name` e retornamos `value` do método criado.
    define_method("name") do
      value
    end
  end
end

class MyClass < UtilsClass
  add_name_getter "Luiz"
end


ins = MyClass.new
p ins.name # => "Luiz"
```

Utilizei o método [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Module.html#method-i-define_method) para adicionar um método às instâncias de `MyClass` de forma dinâmica.